# Windows 2008 security logs file name?

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, event-log

What's the Windows Server 2008 equivalent of the SecEvent.Evt file? So I can open the file itself on an external computer and see who logged in.

Answer (score 2):

On my system, the path to the Security log is

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx
```

but this seems to be configurable.

The general solution is, if you right click on a log in the Event Viewer and choose `Properties`, it will give you the path to that log.

Answer (score 2):

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx
```

Note the different extension, in Server 2008/Vista the event logging system was re-written including new file formats.

Better to use the standard APIs and tools (eg. [`Get-WinEvent`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849682.aspx) in PowerShell) to remotely access than directly accessing the file.